# Hacking the ArduCopter Software

Tags: uav

I'm interested in using software from [diydrones.com](http://diydrones.com) specifically written for UAV helicopters called [ArduCopter](http://code.google.com/p/arducopter/wiki/ArduCopter). However, the instructions on the website assume that you've bought the specialty microcontroller board that diydrones sells.

I'm interested in using their ArduCopter firmware in a simulation using FlightGear and APM Planer as this [QuadHil](http://code.google.com/p/arducopter/wiki/QuadHil) tutorial demonstrates, but I want to use it either without any hardware in-the-loop or with a small Arduino in-the-loop.

Anyone who's played around with this software more than I care to share how difficult this would be, and how I might go about it?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the UAV scene, but this site is primarily about the development of electronics.  It does include their firmware, but development and porting of emulators (which I think, but don't know, that QuadHil is) for use on only PCs is a better fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: May be better asked on the diydrones forums. People there are pretty smart, and can probably address your concerns more directly.

Comment: "Playing around with software" is off-topic and so is robotics. This could be on-topic if it was more about the Arduino and its firmware. I also don't believe "playing around with software" polling type questions are on-topic anywhere on stackexchange.

Comment: @CMP - Are you familiar with diydrones or UAVs?  Can you tell if this is on topic?

Answer (score 1):

For future Googlers,

There are now (Jan 2014) much cheaper Flight Controller boards that use a ported version of ArduPilot (APM). Look up [MegaPirateNG](http://www.megapirateng.com/) and you'll be pleasantly suprized.

So to answer your question, yes, you can port it to different boards, but the hardware out there now is so inexpensive (~50 USD), and the software so good (Mission Planner from ArduPilot and MegaPirateNG firmware) that it only makes sense to port it if you are

1. doing it for a personal or school learning project
2. have a very custom board that makes more sense to keep and use than going with an already debugged and tested Flight Controller.

Note that the size of the firmware is pushing the limits of the current AVR on these Flight Controllers, so a "small Arduino" will likely not be big enough.

Shameless self promotion: I [wrote a paper](http://www.scribd.com/doc/194944623/Multirotor-Control-A-First-Look-at-Flight-Controllers-for-Quadcopters-and-other-Unmanned-Aerial-Vehicles) on Flight Controllers for school a few weeks ago and am in the process of building a quadcopter based on MegaPirateNG's port of ArduCopter firmware. (If you want to see the build blog, there's a link in my profile.)